# Скрытие комментариев к сообщениям при проверке т. н. сообщений низкого качества

Tags: предложение, очередь-проверок

### 1. Актуальное поведение

Пример ссылки на ревизию «низкокачественного сообщения» — **https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/142671**

[image: Низкокачественное сообщение]

Под сообщением располагается шаблонный комментарий `В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша репутация достигнет...`.

---

### 2. Проблема

1. Закрывающие/удаляющие, которые видят шаблонные комментарии, могут менее ответственно относиться к процессу проверки, с меньшей тщательностью вникая в суть сообщений. Проверяющий может согласиться с предыдущими мнениями — особенно от более авторитетных участниц/участников, — и проголосовать за закрытие/удаление с тем же шаблоном, что и у проверяющих до него.
2. Бывает, на этом сайте говорится об «автоматических проверках», когда участники быстро проверяют сообщения, вероятно, для скорого получения знаков. Скрытие комментариев, возможно, подсократит число подобных проверок: ведь на сообщение нужно будет посмотреть, составить мнение на его счёт, а не просто выбрать ту же причину, что и у других, и пойти дальше.

Если скрывать комментарии во время проверки, она может стать более независимой от мнений предшествующих проверяющих. При более объективном рассмотрении понизятся шансы на закрытие/удаление сообщений, соответствующих правилам.

#### 3. Другое поведение

1. При проверке «сообщений низкого качества» проверяющая/проверяющий не видит комментарии.
2. Вероятно, лучше, если она/он не будет видеть только шаблонные комментарии, автоматически добавляемые при голосах за закрытие/удаление.
3. При этом остаётся возможность добавлять собственные комментарии к сообщениям, чтобы помочь их авторам.

Comment: Просто интересно: почему вы пишете «она/он» в каждом предложении? А как же участники с небинарной гендерной идентичностью, почему вы их дискриминируете (не указывая вариантов для них)?

Comment: Хм. Если я вижу подобного рода шаблонный комментарий, понимаю, что проверка уже проведена и предпочитаю нажать `пропустить`. Есть основания не доверять предыдущему проверяющему/проверяющей?

Comment: @vp_arth, неверно. Раз пост в очереди, значит проверка не завершена. Одного голоса недостаточно, чтобы было принято решение.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ок, спасибо, буду знать)

Comment: @vp_arth пропускать имеет смысл, когда нет уверенности в правильности выбора других вариантов.

Answer (score 2):

> Закрывающие/удаляющие... могут менее ответственно относиться к процессу проверки...

Пока что это просто гипотеза об особенности поведения участников. Проблемы в этом нет.

### Гипотеза о проблеме могла бы быть такой

1. В очереди проверок участники удаляют/закрывают то, что стоило оставить и наоборот.
2. Это наносит значимый ущерб содержимому и сообществу.
3. Механика очереди, требующая голосов от многих участников, не работает.
4. Участники голосуют предвзято, потому что видят комментарий. Если его убрать, они будут голосовать непредвзято.

Последний пункт, о котором вы пишете, правдоподобен. Вполне возможно, что комментарий делает голосование насколько-то более предвзятым.

### Но самой проблемы нет

Остальные пункты пока на уровне гипотезы. Даже пример, который вы привели, не иллюстрирует проблему — проверяющие правильно проголосовали.

#### Статистика аудита

Давайте посмотрим на статистику этой очереди. Для начала, аудит. За последний месяц:

```
279 проверок: 94% пройдено
```

Среднестатистический проверяющий ошибается с вероятностью 0.06 или 6%.
Если пессимистично предположить, что все предвзяты и голосуют строго по комментарию, то 6% проверок пройдёт неудачно.

Ошибочные действия при аудите — примерно пополам «Править» и «Выглядит нормально». То есть участники, проваливающие аудит, не удаляют по ошибке. Наоборот, они слишком лояльны к содержимому.

#### Статистика проверок

Теперь посмотрим на отдельных участников и их статистику.
Выбрал нескольких, имеющих не менее 2х аудитов и высокий процент провалов за последний месяц.

```
репутация     N проверок     среднее время     аудитов    провал аудита
8k            82             5                 3          33%
3k            32             28                2          50%
3k            157            24                9          87%
5k            158            18                5          80%
7k            314            34                16         81%
```

Похоже, что у первых двух есть затруднения с пользованием очередью. Мы им напишем, порекомендуем быть внимательнее. Я сейчас вручную перебрал по полтора десятка проверок, в которых они участвовали. Везде, если была ошибка, другие проверяющие сработали корректно и общему процессу проверки это не повредило. Примеры дать не могу, чтобы не раскрывать анонимность.

### Выводы

1. Нет статистики, которая бы указывала на проблему с некорректными *результатами* проверки в очереди.
2. Есть отдельные проверяющие, которые голосуют быстро и/или невнимательно, поэтому ошибаются. Для работы с ними мы можем использовать инструменты модераторов.
3. Даже если проверяющий ошибается, другие «страхуют» его. В очереди проверок у вас есть право на ошибку (а у модераторов нет :( ).